# NullPointerException when creating GoogleApiClient instance

Tags: android

I've started creating Watch Face for Android Wear. I've implemented almost everything and now I want to show on the face the phone battery. From what I understood after my research this is only doable via Message or Data Layer API. So I've started working in his area but I'm facing a problem in the very beginning. I cannot connect to Google Api Client.

I have two classes under "wear" - one generic for the watch (service) and one created by me:

```
public class BatteryActivity extends Activity {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks( new ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                Log.i( "", "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                // Now you can use the Data Layer API
            }
            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                Log.i( "", "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
            }
        })
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener( new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                Log.i( "", "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
            }
        })
                // Request access only to the Wearable API
        .addApi(Wearable.API)
        .build();
}
```

Whan I simply instance it like this: `BatteryActivity batteryActivity = new BatteryActivity();`
I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
>   'android.os.Looper android.content.Context.getMainLooper()' on a null
>   object reference

I don't understand how mGoogleApiClient is null if I've instance it.
As a note - this is purely based on google documentation here - https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html

Comment: Never instantiate Activity class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you should build the GoogleApiClient on `onCreate` method. Your code would be like this:

```
public class BatteryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks( new ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                    Log.i( "", "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                    // Now you can use the Data Layer API
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    Log.i( "", "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener( new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.i( "", "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                }
            })
        // Request access only to the Wearable API
        .addApi(Wearable.API)
        .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It also happens when not providing proper context. Pass context like this :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context) // Pass context here
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should be done via Async task: https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#Communicating

```
private class WatchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    protected void doInBackground(String text) {
```

Or for a quick fix, you may just be using this in the wrong spot:

In your `onCreate` use `getActivity()` or `this` to use a `Context` for this line:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
```

I would also suggest checking out: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

If you really want to use an activity, then it would look something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, MessageApi.MessageListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleClient; // A google client for Wear interaction

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Build a new GoogleApiClient that includes the Wearable API
        googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(googleClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        //Same onMessageReceived as in WearableListenerService
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { }
}
```

Comment: I end up moving the whole logic to the main watch face service. It works for now, however the class looks awful. Now as I have it working I'll see how can I move it. Thanks everyone for the help!